# Laravel: Trying to get property of non object

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have been writing a web application in the Laravel framework andhave come across an issue I am having with getting certain data for a user. The user structure of my web application is based on a main users table, then I have an RP table for all the users statistics such as health, energy, items they own, and so on.

When visiting a page I am trying to display this data on I am receiving the following error

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\workspace\mainwebsite\resources\views\frontend\home.blade.php)
```

O simply tried to print out the user_id column of the roleplay table for the user (and yes, I have tried other columns they output the same result)

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        {{ Auth::user()->roleplay->user_id }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my user table class:

```
<?php
namespace App\Database\Website\User;

use Hash;
use Eloquent;
use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as Authentication;

class Player extends Eloquent implements Authentication
{
    use Authenticatable;

    protected $primaryKey   = 'id';
    protected $table        = 'users';
    public $timestamps      = false;
    protected $fillable     = [];

    public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
    }

    public function setUsernameAttribute($value)
    {
        return $this->attributes['username'] = $value;
    }

    public function roleplay()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Database\Website\User\Roleplay', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Here is my roleplay table class:

```
<?php
namespace App\Database\Website\User;

use Eloquent;

class Roleplay extends Eloquent
{
    protected $primaryKey   = 'id';
    protected $table        = 'srp_user_statistics';
    public $timestamps      = false;
    protected $fillable     = ['user_id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Database\Website\User\Player', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure that your current user has a `roleplay` object. Eloquent will return `null` for empty relationships.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
   @if(Auth::user()->roleplay)
    <div class="panel-body">
        {{ Auth::user()->roleplay->user_id }}
    </div>
    @endif
</div>
```

**Question**: why not just get the authorized user's id (`{{Auth::user()->id}}`) ? It appears that the roleplay object is related to the user on that id anyway; why go through a relationship to fetch an id that you already have?

Related:

[Laravel Blade template how to return null instead of ErrorException when trying to get property of non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41168170/laravel-blade-template-how-to-return-null-instead-of-errorexception-when-trying/41173557#41173557)

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your problem, it seems that you're fetching user's roleplay without actually checking that what `auth()->user()` is originally returning. If there isn't any authenticated user, it will return null.

You should use [`auth()->check()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Auth/GuardHelpers.html#method_check) before fetching user from auth like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        {{ (auth()->check()) ? auth()->user()->roleplay->user_id : '' }}
    </div>
</div>
```

> If the user is currently authenticated, then you should fetch the user details. `auth()->check()` returns a boolean value - false: if user isn't authenticated else it returns true

Hope this helps!

Comment: I already know I am authenticated because I can get data from just the Auth::user()

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the authentication doesn't work in your webapp.

Comment: I already know I am authenticated because I can get data from just the Auth::user()

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty basic debugging, you just need to figure out what part of that expression is not returning an object.

If the user isn't logged in, then `Auth::user()` would return null and since you are chaining `->roleplay` after that, it would give you this error.

If `Auth::user()` is returning something but `Auth::user()->roleplay` returns null, then you would get this error because you are trying to chain `->user_id` onto the end of null.  The likely cause for this would be there is no `roleplay` data in the database for the logged in user or there is something wrong with your relationship.